# SSRS mask rows that are consecutive

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Here is my problem

I've got a resultset with 5 row groups, in the other date displayed (outside of the group) I need to display a number, but in order to shrink the table I'd like to mask all numbers that are following the first one.

Example of my fictive dataset (Destroyed products list):

```
BRAND   MODEL   SUB-MODEL PRICE   DATE       SERIAL(always an integer)
A1      M1      SM-M11    100.0   2015-09-01             100001
A1      M1      SM-M11    100.0   2015-09-01             100002
A1      M1      SM-M11    100.0   2015-09-01             100003
A1      M1      SM-M11    100.0   2015-09-01             200005
A1      M1      SM-M11    100.0   2015-09-01             200006
SkyNet  T800    101       112.0   1984-10-26               1235
SkyNet  T1000   T1001     1000.0  1991-07-01               1287
SW      R2      D2        130.0   1977-05-25               5351
SW      R2      D2        130.0   1977-05-25               5352             
SW      R2      D2        130.0   1977-05-25               5353
```

And here is what should be displayed

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  BRAND |  MODEL | SUB-MODEL | PRICE  | DATE       | SERIAL           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| A1     | M1     | SM-M11    | 100.0  | 2015-09-01 | 100001 to 100003 |
| A1     | M1     | SM-M11    | 100.0  | 2015-09-01 | 200005 to 200006 |
| Skynet | T800   | 101       | 112.0  | 1984-10-26 | 1235             |
| SW     | T1000  | T1001     | 1000.0 | 1991-07-01 | 1287             |
| SW     | R2     | D2        | 130.0  | 1977-05-25 | 5351 to 5353     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I want to hide the row based on this expression

`=CStr(Previous(Fields!Column6.Value)+1) = Cstr(Fields!Column6.Value)`

it doesn't work, only the Column6 can be hidden with such an exception,  and it leaves "holes" in my report as the row groups still appear in front of the line.

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: Can you please show your report design too?

Comment: I can't work out what business rules you are trying to implement based on your example. The first two rows in the "should be displayed" example seem to overlap (i.e. "1 to 3" and "3")?

Comment: @Nathan thanks for pointing me a mistake I've edited my example to remove the line that was overlapping.

Comment: @AnupAgrawal what do yo mean by report design ?

Comment: I've started a new method yesterday to try avoiding groups : I don't put any group in order to be able to remove completely a line, instead of doing groups I order my table and hide the rows based on the expression I've given. But I'm still struggling with this because I'm not able to "store" the value of the first row and also I'm missing the Next evaluator, having just the Previous function is a bit restrictive.

Comment: You should use groups, it'll make everything a lot more easy. Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve in the last column? Do you want the fields inside the same cell? Is the last column always a number and you're trying to split the group based on the missing number? It's quite confusing, could you maybe add a more visual representation of the wanted result?

Comment: That's it I want in the last cell to display the contiguous values of the column 6 (that is always an integer), I've edited what should be displayed to look like a table but I doubt that it will really help you to understand.

Comment: Hiding the rows based on an expression is easy, but this won't help you get the right values in the final column. `=Iif(CStr(Previous(Fields!Column6.Value)+1) == Cstr(Fields!Column6.Value) , True, False)`

Comment: @ChristopheThiry By report design I mean can you show the screenshot of rdl where you design your report. I am trying to understand what do you mean by **5 Row Groups**. Are you creating 5 different groups in your rdl ? Q2. In our output why do you have two rows for Brand A1 even when the data are same? Q3. The output doesn't match the original data. (I understand it is fictive data).

Comment: @AnupAgrawal A1. Sorry I can't, that's why I've put my example as replacement. A2. Yes I create 5 row groups (the 5 first columns) and I want to shrink the number of rows in order to reduce my number of pages currently my report generates 700 pages when the previous version (that was done with crystal reports) was generating only 50 pages. A3. What doesn't match? I don't see my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but without SSRS: I've modified the result of my dataset by modifying the query that was done. Solution is related to this post : [Group consecutive rows that are incremented by 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991863/group-consecutive-rows-that-are-incremented-by-1). None of my attempts to do the same using SSRS was successful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be handling this using grouping - either in your source query for the dataset, or in the report itself. If I were doing this in the report, based on your example dataset I would have a table with grouping on the values of all these columns:

```
BRAND
MODEL
SUB-MODEL
PRICE
DATE
```

It also looks like there is a grouping on the first digit of SERIAL (i.e. (1)00001, (1)00002, (2)00005). Since SERIAL is an integer you should be able to use a grouping expression like `=Left(CStr(Fields!SERIAL.Value), 1)` and then a cell expression of something like `=Min(Fields!SERIAL.Value) & " to " & Max(Fields!SERIAL.Value)`

Comment: Sorry but the serial is something that I can use for grouping : it could be numbers starting at 1 and finishing at 1000000 or so. I'm sorry if the example could give this wrong idea. I'm currently also trying to format the stored procedure from where I extract data in order to get my expected result but it is also tricky as I'm working with an old database that doesn't support some features.

Comment: You'll need to explain the business rules involved in getting from your example dataset to the "what should be displayed" example, otherwise it's going to be very difficult to provide a useful solution. For example if you are not grouping on the first digit of the serial number, why are the first two rows, which are otherwise identical, split into those serial number sequences instead of just one row for serial numbers "100001 to 200006"?